# Given a DFA M, formally define an NFA N such that L(N) = {x in L(M) | x = reverse(x)}

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

The english description of the question is (from my understanding) N accepts all strings that are both palindromic (the same forwards as it is backwards) and accepted by M. After a lot of toil and trouble, I'm not convinced that such a definition of N is even possible. My thinking is as follows:

Say M above is the DFA that accepts the language $(1 + 0)^*$. Then the desired N would describe all palindromes over the language $\{1, 0\}$. However, such a language is not regular (I think). Therefore, is it not the case that such a formal definition is not possible, as NFAs can only describe regular languages?

Perhaps I am missing some subtle nuance in the question, but I believe that such a formal definition is simply not possible. Is my thinking correct?

Comment: Right, if $M$ accepts all strings then your $L(N)$ isn't regular. You're probably misunderstanding the question. Perhaps they want you to find an NFA $N$ such that $L(N) = \{\mathit{reverse}(x) \mid x \in L(M)\}$.

Comment: I wish. Unfortunately, the exact wording of the question is "Given a DFA M, define an NFA N such that L(N) = {x ∈ L(M)|x = reverse(x)}"